# Why can't I use my factors from (factor analysis) to my GLM analysis? SPSS

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss, factor-analysis

I have tried using two factor extracted from principal axis factoring. One for the dependent variabel in SPSS GLM model, and one for the fixed factor.
But the output makes no sense.

If I use one of the same factors as dependent and ONE item for the fixed the output is great.

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in here? (Oversimplifying:) Factor analysis tries to give you the factors that are as independent on each other as possible, so predicting one of the factors by others is not supposed to give you any reasonable results. If you predict the factors using the individual items, then you are using same data twice, so I'm not sure what are you trying to acheive with that either?

Comment: I am trying to test the relationship between loyality and satisfaction by using a univariate GLM model. Since I have 3 items for satisfaction and 5 items for loyalty I wanted to use the factors for loyalty and satisfaction instead. I have just done that with satisfaction (factor) and one single item, and when I do that the output is fine. But when I'm exchanging the item with another factor it won't work - I am sorry if this is a really stupid question, it is my first time working with GLM.

Comment: But if you know which items measure loyalty and which satisfaction, then you don't need factor analysis in here, don't you?

Comment: No, I don't. I am done with the factor analysis. I just want to use the factors I have found in the factor analysis in my univariate general linear model. But when I use the factors I have found in my factor analysis in my general linear model the output from the general linear model makes no sense.

Comment: Please read my first comment once again. Factor analysis forces the factors to be uncorrelated, so lack of the correlation is the expected outcome.

Comment: Okay, so as I read it, it makes no sense to do a univariate GLM with two factors as it will devide the data into groups twice?

Comment: It makes no sense because factor analysis makes your factors uncorrelated by design, so before running the GLM you know that it will tell you that the factors are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the ANOVA results is likely that you have far more categories for the loyalty factor than you anticipated if you extracted factor scores from factor analysis. For clarification, factor analysis can produce uncorrelated factors if you select orthogonal rotation methods (e.g., varimax), or correlated factors if you select oblique rotation methods (e.g., oblimin, promax). In most cases I recommend use of oblique rotation methods so one does not artificially produce uncorrelated factors - if there is naturally no correlation between factors, the correlation produced by oblique methods will be close to zero.

The factors you extracted will be ordinal or interval type, so both the satisfaction and loyalty factor scores will likely contain decimal fractions (e.g., 2.33, 4.15, 3.69, etc.). ANOVA is not designed for predictors like these; rather, ANOVA assumes the predictor, or factor, is categorical with identified groups, maybe coded with whole numbers (e.g. groups 1, 2, 3, etc.).

In short, the confusion here, I think, is that you equated a factor in factor analysis as similar to a factor in ANOVA, and they are not. Factor analysis will produce factor scores that are like continuous variables, while factor analysis treats factors as a categorical variable.

As for analysis options, there are a number. I will start with complex and work toward more simplified suggestions. First, if you want to use ANOVA, run the GLM analysis but treat loyalty as a covariate so you are essentially running an ANCOVA but without a factor, and request that the SPSS GLM analysis provide parameter estimates so you can see the underlying regression equation. Or, simpler and more familiar to many, use regression with satisfaction factor scores as the dependent and loyalty factor scores as the predictor. I recommend, however, that you first create a scatterplot of satisfaction and loyalty factor scores to see the nature of this relationship. Also, if you used an oblique factor rotation method, SPSS will automatically produce a factor correlation matrix and that will show the correlation between the two factors, or you can use SPSS to obtain the Pearson correlation between the set of factor scores which will also answer your question about how they are related.

One other suggestion, I recommend creating two composite variables by taking the mean of the satisfaction items, and then the mean of the loyalty items. Of course use reversed scored items as needed if any items require reverse scoring. The correlation (or regression) results from these composite scores should be similar to those obtained in factor analysis unless you mistakenly used orthogonal rotation to produce factor scores. This approach can serve as a validity check for your analysis - if the composite scores do not correlate well with the factor scores, or do not produce similar results in the above analyses, then something is wrong.

Another thought - in a study like this I probably would not use factor scores for this analysis, I would create mean composite scores and use those to answer my research questions. While many would argue that factor analysis creates a measurement model that should produce more valid scores for satisfaction and loyalty, I don't like this approach for two reasons. First, the factor scores produced are a product of both satisfaction items and loyalty items since factor scores are created by an equation that includes both satisfaction and loyalty items as predictors, e.g.,

F1 = b1S1 + b2S2 + b2S3 + b4L1 + b5L2 + b6L3 + b7L4 + b8L5

where F1 is the satisfaction factor (or loyalty factor), the b are the coefficients, and S1 to S3 are satisfaction items and L1 to L5 are the loyalty items. F2 would be the second factor and it would use a similar equation except that the coefficient weights would differ. As this equation shows, when factor scores are extracted, these scores contain parts of both satisfaction and loyalty. A composite score would not do this, instead, it would look like this:

Satisfaction = 1*S1 + 1*S2 + 1*S3

where the coefficients, b, are all assumed to be 1, and no loyalty items enter the equation. The second reason I prefer composite scores over factor scores is because factor scores are sample specific - the coefficients obtained in one sample will differ in another sample, whereas the weighting coefficients in composite scores are always the same across samples, b = 1, and this often reflects how people use these scores in practice - rather than use factor scores, most practitioners will compute a mean score or a total score for each construct. Having written all this, note that whether you use factor scores or composite scores, the results should be similar in the end.